MapBox heatmap not showing
I have a radar rain data and I am trying to visualize it on the map using MapBox in ReactJs App.
my data is like this...
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"crs":{
"type":"name",
"properties":
{
"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
}
},
"features":[
{
"type":"Feature",
"geometry":{
"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[73.30707,34.029724]
},
"properties":{
"name":"heatmap",
"id":"34.02972473.30707",
"rainIndex":1
}
},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[73.415016,33.79824]},"properties":{"name":"heatmap","id":"33.7982473.415016","rainIndex":7}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[73.33405,33.65935]},"properties":{"name":"heatmap","id":"33.6593573.33405","rainIndex":24}},]}

and I am doing like this.
useEffect(() => {
if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once
map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: mapContainer.current,
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12",
  center: [lng, lat],
  zoom: zoom,
});
map.current.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");
map.current.on("move", () => {
  setLng(map.current.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
  setLat(map.current.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
  setZoom(map.current.getZoom().toFixed(2));
});


map.current.on("style.load", () => {
  map.current.addSource('rain', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': JSON.stringify(geoJSON)
});


  map.current.addLayer({
    id: "rain-heat",
    type: "heatmap",
    source: "rain",
    paint: {
      'heatmap-intensity': ['interpolate', ['linear'], ['get', 'rainIndex'], 1, 0, 30, 1],
      'heatmap-color': [
          'interpolate',
          ['linear'],
          ['heatmap-density'],
          0, 'blue',
          0.5, 'green',
          1, 'red'
      ],
  },
  });

  
});

}, [features]);
Map is showing on the screen but heatmap is not producing. I am new at MapBox so please don't mind if I made any mistake. TIA :)
